# .getDay() not working in IE and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, safari

Im trying to program a calender, where the user can select a date to make an appointment. The calender itself works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE and Safari which it has to. I broke the code down to find the line which causes the problem:

```
var firstday = new Date(kalenderYear + "," + kalenderMonth + ",01").getDay();
```

"firstday" should get the weekday of the first day in the month (for example "3" for october, because the 1. of october was wednesday).

This line of code works only in Chrome and Firefox. Any ideas how i could make it work in all major browsers?

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: I outputted the variable "firstday" after setting it. In Chrome and Firefox its just the weekday. In Safari and IE its "NaN". But no real errors.

Comment: doesn't appear to be valid date string

Comment: Look at my answer. You are using a string instead of the numbers needed to create the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will fix your problem since you haven't posted all your code but it should be like this:

```
var firstday = new Date(kalenderYear, kalenderMonth, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).getDay();
```

Comment: I tried it, but IE still outputs "NaN" as the value of "firstday"

Comment: Then you have more of a problem. Use console.log(kalendarYear, kalendarMonth); before this line and see what they are.

Comment: Also may want to try using var firstday = new Date(parseInt(kalenderYear), parseInt(kalenderMonth), 1).getDay();

Comment: still not working, but thanks! both variables (kalenderYear, kalenderMonth) are integer.

Comment: Ok one more thing to try. IE doesn't like all date formats so try including the time numbers in there like so: var firstday = new Date(kalenderYear, kalenderMonth, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).getDay();

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var data = new Date();
var dateOfWeek = data.getDay();
```

print the day of week, today is wednesday, then number 3
Bye